# How to determine if a function has a zero vector in order for it to be a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

I am extremely confused because the problem is asking me to define whether or not the following function is a subspace. "All twice differentiable functions defined on the real line in the space of all continuous functions defined on the real line". I know I have to prove whether or not the zero vector exists but how can I do it when twice differentiable functions can either cross the origin or stay above the axis? How would I prove whether or not something is a subspace when I am given a type of function, and not a specific function itself?

Comment: @RobertShore "All twice differentiable functions defined on the real line in the space of all continuous functions defined on the real line." You were right, I forgot to mention that it is the set of all, but how would this change? Because if it is a set that just means that each differentiable function is a vector right?

Comment: You need to prove, among other things, that the zero function falls within the set of twice-differentiable functions defined on the real line.  What about that?  Is the constant $0$ function twice differentiable?  The difference is that you just need to prove that the constant $0$ function falls within that set, not that every twice-differentiable function is the constant $0$ function.  Think about it in settings that are more familiar to you.  You don't need to prove that every vector is the zero vector.  You just need to prove that zero is included in your putative subspace.

Comment: @Ben It doesn't make sense to say that a function is a vector space or that a function has a zero vector. On the other hand, it is completely reasonable to ask whether a **set** of functions is a vector space or has a zero vector.

Comment: @RobertShore I see, so in a set of functions that all have the same quality, I have to prove whether or not the constant 0 function can have that quality?

Comment: Yes, you have to prove that the constant $0$ function *does* (not can) have that quality.  Of course, you also have to prove the usual closure axioms to be sure your set really is a subspace.  Once you understand what you need to prove (and I think you're getting there), it should all be pretty easy with this particular set.  Let me suggest giving this a try by answering your own question.

Comment: @RobertShore Alright then, so since the constant 0 function which would be f(x)=0 is twice differentiable, therefore all twice differentiable functions on a real line are in a subspace. (I have not learned about usual closure axioms yet)

Comment: No, not yet. You’d better review the definition of subspace, and then check that your set satisfies all the conditions therein.

Comment: To show that the set is a subspace, you also need to show that (a) the sum of any two set members is also in the set, and (b) the product of any real number $\alpha$ by any member of the set $f(x)$ is also in the set.  It's not hard, but it gets you used to proving subspaces in more abstract settings.